# Assume $\boldsymbol 1^\top A \boldsymbol 1 = 1$. Is $A$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix. Also, let $\boldsymbol 1$ be a $n \times 1$ matrix in which every entry is $1$. Assume that $\boldsymbol 1^\top A \boldsymbol 1 = 1$. Can we show that $A$ is invertible?

**My attempt:** It follows from $\boldsymbol 1^\top A \boldsymbol 1 = 1$ that $\boldsymbol 1\boldsymbol 1^\top A \boldsymbol 1 \boldsymbol 1^\top = \boldsymbol 1\boldsymbol 1^\top$. Then $|\boldsymbol 1\boldsymbol 1^\top|^2 |A| = |\boldsymbol 1\boldsymbol 1^\top|$. However, $|\boldsymbol 1\boldsymbol 1^\top| = 0$, so I'm unable to get anything new.

Comment: You need to try some basic stuff yourself. Is ${1 \over n^2}1 1^T$ invertible?

Comment: In other words, why should it be? Your equation simply fixes to one a certain matrix element of $A$.

Comment: The condition is equivalent to "the sum of the entries of $A$ is $1$." A matrix with all zero entries except a single "$1$" entry satisfies this condition and isn't invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify the notation, we set
$$
A = \left[ \matrix{0 & 1 \cr
                  0 & 0 \cr} \right], \
U=\left[\matrix{1 \cr 1 \cr} \right]
$$

Note that
$$
U^T A U = 1
$$

However, $A$ is singular as obviously, $\mbox{det}(A) = 0$.

This counterexample establishes that the claim in the problem is not true.